# Как создать 10 копий файла?

Tags: python

я за помощью.

Как в Python создать 10 копий файла?
Мой код не работает:

```
a=open("D:\\python21\\long.txt","r")
b=open("D:\\python21\\str(i).txt","w")
for i in range(11):
    b.write(a.read())
a.close()
b.close()
```

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, свой вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: Примечание переводчика, то есть меня. Судя по попыткам в коде, нужно всё же 10 файлов, а не 10 копий одного файла в другом, как это сделано у @S. Nick

Comment: @SergeyNudnov плохой из меня переводчик :)

Comment: @S.Nick Мне, как всем беларусам, полегче. По-русски говорим, по-украински, по-польски и ещё по всякому - понимаем. :)

Comment: Обратите внимание на название вашего исходного файла: long.txt. Это намекает, что плохая идея считывать его в память, а потом записывать снова на диск - просто для копирования. Если его размер, например, 4GB, то будет ой. Так что ответ @extrn наиболее оптимальный.

Answer (score 4):

```py
from shutil import copyfile

for i in range(1, 11):
    copyfile(r'D:\python21\long.txt', rf'D:\python21\str({i}).txt')
```